# win32 API open a jpg in a picture control c++

Tags: c++, api, winapi, jpeg

i want to know if there's a way to print a jpg onto a picture control rectangle (that i build with ResEdit) the action that should print the image is  case IDC_BUTTON1: and the target i want to view the image is in a picture control with the id: IDC_STATIC

```
BOOL CALLBACK AppDlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch(uMsg)
  {

  case WM_INITDIALOG:
      DragAcceptFiles(hDlg,true);
    SetClassLongPtr(hDlg, GCLP_HICON, (long)LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION));
    return 1;
  case WM_COMMAND:
   switch(wParam)
    {
    case IDOK:
  return 0;
case IDCANCEL:
  EndDialog(hDlg, 0);
}
 switch(wParam)
        {
            case IDC_BUTTON1:
               ShellExecute(hDlg,
         "open",
         "C:\immagine1.jpg",
         NULL,
         NULL,
         SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
            break;
        }

  switch(wParam)
        {
            case IDC_BUTTON4:
               ShellExecute(hDlg,
         "open",
         "C:\log.txt",
         NULL,
         NULL,
         SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
            break;
        }






  }
  return 0;
}
```

instead of using shell execute that open the default viewer thank you all

Comment: The [OleLoadPicturePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function can load a JPEG file. Then it's just a matter of accessing the bits. Oh well, it involves a bit of "reading the documentation", and I don't have time to flesh out the details here. Nor do I, any longer, have code for this. I just remember this approach from about 10 years back or so. There's also the [Windows Imaging Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719902%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) API, but I haven't used that. I suspect that it also works, though, and it may b

Comment: once i've loaded the image how can i sent the message to the picture control?
I've saw the procedure to load a bmp, nothing in jpg...

Comment: hm, lemme try. might take some time though. not continuous free time

Answer (score 2):

The [`OleLoadPicturePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function can load a JPEG file.

Then it's just a matter of accessing the bits.

There's also the [Windows Imaging Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719902%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) API, but I haven't used that.

I suspect that it also works, though, and it may be simpler than dealing with the OLE stuff, but here I exemplify `OleLoadPicturePath`.

Before trying to adapt the code below, you should:

- Make sure that the type of the picture control resource is set to BITMAP (essentially, at the .rc text level, that it has the `SS_BITMAP` style).
- Change the ID to something unique, instead of `IDC_STATIC`.

[image]

```
#include <header_wrapper/olectl_h.h>        // IPicture
#include <header_wrapper/windows_h.h>
#include "resource.h"       // IDD_DEMO_DIALOG, IDC_PICTURE

#include <progrock/cppx/throwx.h>           // hopefully, throwX, std::exception
#include <progrock/cppx/size.h>             // size
#include <progrock/winapi/path.h>           // *
#include <progrock/winapi/ComPointer.h>     // ComPointer
using namespace progrock;

#include <assert.h>         // assert
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>         // EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS
using namespace std;

using cppx::hopefully;
using cppx::size;
using cppx::throwX;

using winapi::String;

struct IsHrSuccess
{
    friend bool operator>>( HRESULT const hr, IsHrSuccess const& )
    {
        return SUCCEEDED( hr );
    }
};

IsHrSuccess const   isHrSuccess = IsHrSuccess();

short kindOf( IPicture const& pic )
{
    short kind  = 0;
    const_cast< IPicture& >( pic ).get_Type( &kind )
        >> isHrSuccess || throwX( "kindOf: IPicture::get_Type failed" );
    return kind;
}

bool isBitmap( IPicture const& pic )
{
    return (kindOf( pic ) == PICTYPE_BITMAP);
}

OLE_HANDLE handleOf( IPicture const& pic )
{
    OLE_HANDLE  result  = 0;
    const_cast< IPicture& >( pic ).get_Handle( &result )
        >> isHrSuccess || throwX( "handleOf: IPicture::get_Handle failed" );
    return result;
}

HBITMAP bmpHandle( IPicture const& pic )
{
    assert( isBitmap( pic ) );
    return reinterpret_cast< HBITMAP >( handleOf( pic ) );
}

namespace g {
    winapi::ComPointer<IPicture>  pPicture;
}  // namespace g

INT_PTR CALLBACK demoDialogProc(
    HWND const      window,
    UINT const      messageId,
    WPARAM const    wParam,
    LPARAM const    lParam
    )
{
    switch( messageId )
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        ::SendDlgItemMessage(
            window, IDC_PICTURE, STM_SETIMAGE,
            IMAGE_BITMAP,
            reinterpret_cast< LPARAM >( bmpHandle( *g::pPicture ) )
            );
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        ::EndDialog( window, IDCANCEL );
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        ::EndDialog( window, wParam );
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

struct Com
{
    Com() { ::CoInitialize( 0 ) >> isHrSuccess || throwX( "::CoInitialize failed" ); }
    ~Com() { ::CoUninitialize(); }
};

void cppMain()
{
    Com usingCom;
    String const    picFileName     = L"image.jpg";
    String const    picFilePath     = winapi::path::combine( winapi::exeFolder(), picFileName );

    ::OleLoadPicturePath(
        const_cast< wchar_t* >( picFilePath.c_str() ),
        nullptr, 0, 0,
        IID_IPicture,
        g::pPicture.asOutArgument()
        )
        >> isHrSuccess || throwX( "OleLoadPicturePath failed" );
    assert( isBitmap( *g::pPicture ) );

    ::DialogBox( ::GetModuleHandle( 0 ), MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDD_DEMO_DIALOG ), 0, demoDialogProc );
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        cppMain();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( exception const& x )
    {
        wcout << "!" << x.what() << endl;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```